# Lift With OpenLayers Timing

Tags: openlayers, lift

I have a simple lift "application" that attempts to display statically an OpenLayers map in anticipation of having comet dynamically add markers to the map based on some server-side logic.  In any case, just having the map show up at all is proving to be a difficult task.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script>
  function init() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("mainMap");
    var mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
    var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
    var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
    var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-76.6778,39.2652).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);
    var zoom           = 9; 

    map.addLayer(mapnik);
    map.setCenter(position, zoom );
  }
</script>
</head>


<body class="lift:content_id=main" onload="init();">
<div id="main" class="lift:surround?with=bootstrap;at=content">
      <div id="mainMap"> </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am obviously having a difficult time understanding where the lift-generated head and body elements are coming from after lift:surround has worked its magic.  Though the static HTML looks fine, the pertinent script elements are gone and there seems to be no way to invoke init() in order to have the map appear.

Do I have to override the surround snippit somehow, avoid using it at all, or construct all of the init() javascript within a snippit and then invoke it somehow?  Or something else?  I am a bit of a lift newbie so please bear with me if I am way off base ;)

One other thing I tried is adding the relevant head / script HTML code in the bootstrap.html file I am using to surround the posted page, and that doesn't get me where I want to be either.

Edit:  There was a (usual) caching issue which was preventing me from seeing the changes to the bootstrap.html file specified to the lift:suround snippit.  That actually did work.

Comment: Did you try using the `<head_merge>` tag inside of the `lift:surround` snippet? That should merge the content inside of that into the `<head>` section of the template.

Comment: I tried <head_merge>.  I forgot to include that in the question, and for that I apologize.  The problem is really twofold:

1. I don't know how the default lift snippits work, which are replacing the HTML <head> and <body>, so I don't know where, if anywhere to override its behavior.

2.  The OpenLayers documentation makes exclusive use of the body's "onload" attribute to call the javascript that sets up the map.  <head_merge> still results in a newly-created <body> in the generated HTML that comes from Lift.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read >5 pages about Lift?... When you type content_id=main, you tell Lift to ignore everything except the inner part of the `<div id="main">`. So, for all this to work, place `<head_merge>` with the scripts inside the `<div id="main">`.

http://simply.liftweb.net/index-2.1.html

http://demo.liftweb.net/templating/head

Comment: I know.  And if you had actually read what I posted you should have noticed the contradiction: the <head> specified in the bootstrap.html file given as an argument to lift:surround had the relevant <script>s in it already and was *not working*.  This is because a third-party application I was using was serving a cached version of said html file and was never reflecting the changes I just described.  Hence the confusion.